# Is there a way to access Rails 6 secrets.yml hash as dot notation object

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I would like to access `Rails.application.secrets` as an object till its deeper length.

**Example**: *../config/secrets.yml*

```
development:
  secret_key_base: ""
  my_data:
    user_email: "abc@example.io"
    external_service:
      remote:
        password: ""
      local:
        password: ""
```

Presently Remote password of an external service is fetched using:

> Rails.application.secrets.my_data[:external_service][:remote][:password]

Instead I would like to access it as below:

> Rails.application.secrets.my_data.external_service.remote.password

Is there a way that I can configure my application to behave in above format?

**Note**:

- Only config/secrets.yml must be affected
- Please specify the file path/name where the configurations must be changed/added
- Also suggest if there is an alternate way(gem, etc)

Comment: You'd need to convert your YAML to a Struct or OpenStruct to get the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to put this in an initializer and achieve what you're looking for:

```
Rails.application.secrets = JSON.parse(Rails.application.secrets.to_json, object_class: OpenStruct)
```

Comment: I have placed it in config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_5_1.rb

This solution worked at application level but doesn't take affect within /config/ directory. Ex: in settings.yml file and environments/test.rb file.
Throws: NoMethodError: undefined method `external_service' for #<Hash:0x0000000009a0f790>

Any workaround for this? Thank you.